# State-time fixed effects in Staggered Difference-in-Difference

Tags: r, causal-inference

I was trying to implement state-year fixed effects in R (did package) but the code kept running.

```
out1 <- att_gt(yname  = "y", 
               tname   = "year",
               idname  = "id_county",
               gname   = "p_year",
               #xformla = ~1,
               xformla = ~ factor(time)*factor(year),
               control_group = "notyettreated",
               panel = T,
               clustervars = "id_county",
               est_method = "dr",
               data    = da)
```

Then, I read [this paper](https://viquibarone.github.io/baronevictoria/Opioids_ArteagaBarone.pdf) and found that state-year fixed effect is not possible to implemented in the staggered difference-in-difference model.

[image]

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Hi Will H., welcome to SO. It is important to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Also, please do not add text as an image for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121). Instead, add the text as text. Thanks